# adding a static route with nmcli to virtual bridge breaks kvm networking but

Tags: networking, linux-networking

I have a virtual bridge br0 created with nmcli, with a physical ethernet interface attached to it

the bridge device is the used with kvn virt-manager virtual machines.
They get a static IP address.
For instance, one VM gets the IP address 192.168.39.11
The host is 192.168.39.10

:

```
root@black:/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections# nmcli con show
NAME               UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
br0                a4a276d8-cbdb-4119-83f9-4a7403e98adf  bridge    br0    
netplan-eno2       80ab1970-e833-372e-8635-f330b7d9f1f0  ethernet  eno2   
netplan-eno1       10838d80-caeb-349e-ba73-08ed16d4d666  ethernet  eno1   
rumahtumi          c9c05065-f2f8-48b5-a3bb-b794776a805a  wifi      wlp9s0 
virbr0             d5dcf8cb-80f2-448c-b468-d9b1d4ab2e86  bridge    virbr0 
bridge-slave-eno2  cf0b153e-8a4f-48e1-9a0b-bdf83e80d6c8  ethernet  --
```

It works well, but traffic between the host and the VM seems to go out to the network and back.
At least, if I do this:

```
ip route add 192.168.39.11/32 dev br0
```

and then
 `ping 192.168.39.11`
the average ping time halves.
The same benefit is then seen from the VM back to the host.

but `ip route add ``` ... is not permanent

So I try this:

```
nmcli connection modify br0 +ipv4.routes 192.168.39.11/32
```

and then down and up the br0 connection (or reboot).
however, from this point on, the VM has no route to the network, it does not get a DHCP lease.

So the `nmcli connection modify`  is either wrong, or it works differently to adding the route with `ip route add`

Update: when I compare a backed-up .nmconnection file to the one modified by the `nmcli connection modify...` there are two changes.
One is:

```
...
[ipv4]
method=auto
route1=192.168.39.11/32
```

and the other which I ignore is a
`timestamp` line in the `[connection]` section.
I have removed that and it seems to work now. Although I have to down the original connection for the second ethernet interface, and up the br0

EDIT:
I think my problem is more likely this: when adding a route, nmcli was removing the slave connection and therefore disabling the bridge.